# The smallest number of containers that contain all given elements

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, semantic-analysis

Suppose `C` refers to a set of containers `{c1,c2,c3....cn}`, where each of these containers contains a finite set of integers `{i1,i2,i3...im}`. Further, suppose that it is possible for an integer to exist in more than one container. Given a finite set of integers `S` `{s1,s2,s3...sz}`, find the size of the smallest subset of `C` that contains all integers in `S`.

Note that there could be thousands of containers each with hundreds of integers. Therefore, brute force is slow for solving this problem.

I tried to solve the problem using Greedy algorithm. That is, each time I select the container with the largest number of integers in the set `S`, but I failed!

Can anyone suggest a fast algorithm for this problem?

Comment: How does the algorithm relate to bioinformatics?

Comment: This is the well known [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). It is NP-complete, and so no efficient algorithm is known. The greedy algorithm does as well as can be done (unless P=NP).

Comment: I am trying to find the smallest window size of GO terms that contains all the given genes....For the sake of simplicity, I used integers and containers.

Comment: @GarethRees: This would be a good answer.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: that makes sense, but since it doesn't relate to the question directly I removed the tag. I'm sorry you had to come across an NP problem like that in your research (I also work in bioinformatics)- it's happened to everyone!

Comment: thanks Gareth Rees...I will read about it.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: When you say the greedy algorithm failed, do you mean that it didn't find the optimal solution, that it was slow, or that you weren't able to implement it?

Comment: by "failed", I mean it gave me a wrong output. There is a case where this algorithm fails. "The one I mentioned".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the well known [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). It is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) — in fact, its decision version was one of the canonical NP-complete problems and was among the 21 problems included in [Karp's 1972 paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172/karp.pdf) — and so no efficient algorithm is known. Unless you can identify some special extra structure to the problem, you will have to be satisfied with an approximate result: that is, a subset of C whose union contains S, which but which is not necessarily the *smallest* such subset of C.

The [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover#Greedy_algorithm) is probably your best bet: it finds a collection of sets that is no more than O(log |C|) times the size of the smallest such collection.

You say that you were unable to get the greedy algorithm to work. I think this is probably because you failed to implement it correctly. You describe your algorithm like this:

> each time I select the container with the largest number of integers in the set S

but the rule in the usual greedy algorithm is to select at each stage the container with the largest number of integers in the set S *that are not in any container selected so far*.

Comment: Maybe there is something that I am missing here,
suppose we have S = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
and we have 3 containers, c1= {1,3,4,6}, c2={1,2,3}, c3={4,5,6}
Implementing the greedy algorithm...I will pick in the first stage c1 because it's the largest with uncovered elements....After that I will have to take c2 and then c3. This is obviously not the right solution....because I can take c2 and c3 only....what do you think?

Comment: Since the problem is NP-complete, you cannot expect to compute the smallest cover in a reasonable amount of time. The greedy algorithm is therefore an *approximate algorithm*: it computes *a* cover, but not always the *smallest* cover. If it is important to you that you find the smallest cover, then you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Gareth Rees for your help.